# Why does Visual Studio 2015 lock up when editing a .json file?

Tags: json, visual-studio-2015

I created a brand new file named `RequireJS.json` in Visual Studio 2015, and while typing and copying and pasting to build my JSON object, I noticed that VS would continually lock up for around 10-20 seconds at a time. This seemed to happen more often as I switched tabs, then came back to the .json file. I restarted VS, then restarted the computer, but it continued doing this. No other files or file types are lagging like this. Why would this happen only with .json files?

Answer (score 7):

Since this was only occurring with JSON files, I wondered if it had something to do with Visual Studio's text editor, so I took a look at the VS options under Text Editor -> JSON. I noticed under the "Schema" section, it was pointing to a schema catalog at an external URL (http://schemastore.org/api/json/catalog.json in my case). I unchecked this box, with the thought that VS might be lagging trying to download the file or something, and that must be right because I haven't experienced any VS lags or lockups since unchecking that box.